# red5 web app provide external static resource

Tags: red5, static-resource

I am new to Red5. From my Red5 webapp I need to provide static content (in external directory) as a resource. In red5-web.xml,

```
       <mvc:resources mapping="/videos/**" location="file:/user/recordings/" />
```

I spent lot of time but could not figure out why its not working (getting 404).
Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Red5 uses embedded Tomcat for its Java EE container, you should be able to externally link resources via their configuration. In addition, there should be no restrictions that I know of when using Spring MVC (if that's what you're using).
Here are some links for you to review:

[Tomcat Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

[Serving external images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps)

[Source paths and Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138701/difference-between-tomcats-extraresourcepaths-and-aliases-to-access-an-external)